# Permission Denied Error when Creating file in Java/Springboot - Tomcat

Tags: java, linux, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am trying to create a File in Java/SpringBoot and writing to it using FileWriter Method.
Below is my Code.

```
                String filename = file.csv;
                LOGGER.info("Creating File CSV");
                File file = new File(filename);
                Boolean Isexists =file.exists();
                boolean isexistsabs = file.getAbsoluteFile().exists();
                LOGGER.info("CSV File Exists? : "+Isexists);
                LOGGER.info("CSV File ABSExists? : "+isexistsabs);
                boolean setwritable = file.setWritable(true);
                LOGGER.info("SetWritable CSV Output : "+Boolean.toString(setwritable));
                boolean setExecutable = file.setExecutable(true);
                LOGGER.info("SetExecutable CSV Output : "+Boolean.toString(setExecutable));
                LOGGER.info("before file Writer CSV");
                FileWriter filewriter = new FileWriter(filename);
                LOGGER.info("after file Writer CSV");
                LOGGER.info("Writing File CSV");
                String content ="Some CSV Content";
                filewriter.write(content);
                LOGGER.info("Written to File CSV");
                filewriter.close();
                LOGGER.info("Closing File CSV");
```

When I execute the code in my local system it is working and below is the log of the code

```
2020-07-28 00:56:17.204  INFO 15956 --- Controller       : Creating File CSV
2020-07-28 00:56:17.205  INFO 15956 --- Controller       : CSV File Exists? : true
2020-07-28 00:56:17.206  INFO 15956 --- Controller       : CSV File ABSExists? : true
2020-07-28 00:56:17.206  INFO 15956 --- Controller       : SetWritable CSV Output : true
2020-07-28 00:56:17.207  INFO 15956 --- Controller       : SetExecutable CSV Output : true
2020-07-28 00:56:17.207  INFO 15956 --- Controller       : before file Writer CSV
2020-07-28 00:56:17.208  INFO 15956 --- Controller       : after file Writer CSV
2020-07-28 00:56:17.209  INFO 15956 --- Controller       : Writing File CSV
2020-07-28 00:56:17.209  INFO 15956 --- Controller       : Written to File CSV
2020-07-28 00:56:17.210  INFO 15956 --- Controller       : Closing File CSV
```

But when I execute the same after deploying to a tomcat server below is the log/error I am recieveing

```
2020-07-27 14:34:15.465  INFO 17902 --- Controller       : Creating File CSV
2020-07-27 14:34:15.465  INFO 17902 --- Controller       : CSV File Exists? : false
2020-07-27 14:34:15.465  INFO 17902 --- Controller       : CSV File ABSExists? : false
2020-07-27 14:34:15.466  INFO 17902 --- Controller       : SetWritable CSV Output : false
2020-07-27 14:34:15.466  INFO 17902 --- Controller       : SetExecutable CSV Output : false
2020-07-27 14:34:15.466  INFO 17902 --- Controller       : before file Writer CSV
2020-07-27 14:34:15.488 ERROR 17902 --- [http-nio-8080-exec-31] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/api/getFlighPlanCSV] due to exception [file.csv (Permission denied)]

java.io.FileNotFoundException: file.csv (Permission denied)
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:291) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:123) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:66) ~[na:na]
    at com.aiknights.com.rapidviewmain.controller.SiteInspectionController.DownloadFlightPlan(SiteInspectionController.java:175) ~[classes/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.1.RELEASE.jar:5.2.1.RELEASE]
```

It seems to be erroring out when writing into the file saying File not found, seems like the application/.war is not able to create a file in the PWD because of the permission issue.

```
My application name - applicationmain.war
resides at - /opt/tomcat/webapps/applicationmain.war
there is also a folder created whenever I deploy the war file - /opt/tomcat/webapps/applicationmain
I tried assiging all permissions to both the war file itself and the folder that is created when deploying the war file with no luck
```

I will answer to any comments asking for more details about the setup and code.

Any kind of help would be really appreciated as I already spent too many hours on dealing with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that you have read and execute access to all parent directories as well.

Example:

```
chmod o+x /opt
```

Comment: Well you need to look at the user the application using and make sure it has the permission to access the file. It is clearly unix file system permission issue, no issues with code. you are probably missing something.